# convert json to xml without changing the order of parameters in python

Tags: python, json, xml

I'm using Json2xml module for converting json format to xml format.  But, while converting it changes the order of the parameters.  How do I convert without changing the order of parameters?  Here's my python code.

```
from json2xml.json2xml import Json2xml

data = Json2xml.fromjsonfile('example.json').data
data_object = Json2xml(data)
xml_output = data_object.json2xml()
print xml_output
```

example.json

```
{
    "action": {
      "param1": "aaa",
      "param2": "bbb"
    }
}
```

The output is

```
<action>
<param2>bbb</param2>
<param1>aaa</param1>
</action>
```

Is there a way to convert json to xml without changing the order of parameters?

Answer (score 4):

Try using an `OrderedDict`:

```
from collections import OrderedDict
from json2xml.json2xml import Json2xml

data = Json2xml.fromjsonfile('example.json').data
data = OrderedDict(data)
data_object = Json2xml(data)
xml_output = data_object.json2xml()
print xml_output
```

Comment: What's the difference?  I don't want the items to be sorted.  I just want them in the same order as in json.

Comment: If you switch the order of the element in your `example.json` you will see order change reflected in the outputted XML